# Heap memory vector initilization in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, heap-memory

I am confused between

`vector<node>* children = new vector<node>;`

`vector<node> *children = new vector<node>;`

`vector<node*> children = new vector<node>;`

I just want to implement a general tree data structure as

```
struct node{
    int index;
    vector<int> sol;
    vector<node *> children;
};

node *createNode(int indexVal)
{
    node* n = new Node();
    n->index = indexVal;

    vector<int>* soll = new vector<int>;
    n->sol = soll;

    vector<node>* childrenn = new vector<node *>;
    n->children = childrenn;

    return n;
}

void addChildren(node* curr, node* child)
{
//something like
    curr->push_back(child);
};
```

I want to be able to modify sol and children vector in which ever scope I want, given that I have a node pointer

I am confused which one of the three given will be the best results, how will they differ?
Also how would this extend to 2-d vectors?

Comment: No don't store pointers in a vector. They are intended to hold (movable) objects.
Also in current C++ you hardly need new/delete (and pointers), so if you want to type that... first look for another solution. In your case `std::vector<int> soll;` will be enough. You also will not need to make your own list, there is [std::list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) for that. [Introduction to std::vector](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/an-introduction-to-stdvector/). Note vector is NOT a mathematical vector it is a container/collection of int.

Comment: You need better understanding when and why `new` should be used (Hint: In modern C++ very rarely).

Comment: vector<int> is fine, what I am troubled with is vector<node*> 
I have corrected the question for the same.

Comment: All three are wrong. `vector<node *> children;` is fine but it is not a pointer, so don't use `new` to create it. It is a vector of pointers, so use `new` to create any `node` that you add to the vector.

Comment: @sklott Now I am curious. How one would create a tree without using pointers (and by consequence eventually new/delete)?

Comment: @HadleySiqueira To create a tree without pointers, you can use an array, something similar to how you represent heaps as tree, but I think the limitation is it has to be a complete tree. 

An array with N integers P1,P2,…PN. If Pi=0, that means node i is the root. Otherwise, node i points at node Pi.

Comment: @HadleySiqueira The point that sklott is making is that you don't need to *explicitly* use `new`, you could use `std::unique_ptr<Node>` for example. Of course you must use dynamic allocation and pointers somewhere, but it doesn't have to be in your code, it could be in library code.

Comment: @HadleySiqueira I didn't say "never use new". In this case `new Node` is valid and probably better than using `std::unique_ptr`, but other uses are obviously invalid. And in general in modern C++ using `new` is normal in library code (containers, C library wrappers or whatever) but using it in "bussiness logic" code is bad sign.

Answer (score 4):

You have this:

```
vector<node *> children;
```

That is fine, it's a vector of pointers to `node`s.  You do not use `new` to create it, it is created automatically whenever you have a `node`.  So:

```
node *createNode(int indexVal)
{
    node* n = new node();
    n->index = indexVal;
    return n;
}
```

The `node` has `sol` and `children` vectors directly inside it.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding

```
vector<int>* children = new vector<int>;
```

and

```
vector<int> *children = new vector<int>;
```

They are the same. Both are declaring a pointer to a vector< int>. The only difference is the position of the *. Some people think it is more readable when the * is closer to the type name. Others prefer the * closer to the variable name.

Although I prefer the first one, which puts the * closer to type, the second one is more correct because in C++ the parser associates the * with the variable and not with the type. Thus one could declare the following:

```
vector<int> *ptr1, var2, *ptr2, *ptr3, var3
```

This would declare variables ptr1, ptr2 and ptr3 as being pointers to vector< int> while var2 and var3 would be normal variables. If you use the first writing style and write:

```
vector<int>* ptr1, var2, ptr2, ptr3, var3
```

Believing that all variables would be pointers, you would be wrong. Only ptr1 would be a pointer and all the others would be normal variables.

Now this

```
vector<node*> children = new vector<node>;
```

Is a completely different thing. While on the first two you're declaring a pointer to an array of ints, on the third one you are declaring an array of pointers to int. Also, note the typo you made on the new where you forget the *. To work, it would need to be (note the * at the end)

```
vector<node*> children = new vector<node*>;
```

Regarding your code, it seems that sol is the data stored in the node and children contains the pointers to the other nodes. So I believe in this case the following is correct

```
struct node{
    int index;
    vector<int> sol;
    vector<node *> children;
};
```

And here

```
node *createNode(int indexVal)
{
    node* n = new Node();
    n->index = indexVal;

    /* This is wrong and unecessary. As sol is not a pointer, when 
       you do a new above, the new already allocates the sol so that
       you don't need to allocate again here */
    vector<int>* soll = new vector<int>; // remove this
    n->sol = soll; // not needed

    /* Now here you have some typos. It should be vector<node *> and not 
       vector<node>* */
    vector<node>* childrenn = new vector<node *>;
    n->children = childrenn;

    return n;
}
```

I didn't make any comments on the tree itself as you posted just a skeleton code instead of the real one. I assume you know trees and just wanted to know the C++ stuff regarding pointers and vector. If you don't know trees yet, look closer to your code because there are some parts that are not quite right.

Comment: the thing stylistically "wrong" here is defining so many variables in the same statement. if you ever find yourself doing this, question the quality of your code.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I agree with you, but as C++ allows this and as we don't know his/her level of knowledge I explained it anyways.

Comment: Hadley Siqueira wrote "vector<int>* ptr1, var2, ptr2, ptr3, var3
Believing that all variables would be pointers, you would be wrong. Only ptr1 would be a pointer and all the others would be normal variables"

Finally someone agreeing that char* p, q is totally misleading!

Comment: Actually, ``vector<node*> children = new vector<node*>;`` is not correct, either. No need for ``new`` here anyway.

Comment: @ChristianHalaszovich true. Didn't see that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The first two declarations are equivalent:

```
vector<node>* children = new vector<node>;
vector<node> *children = new vector<node>;
```

They declare a pointer to a dynamic vector.

The third declaration:

```
vector<node*> children = new vector<node>;
```

declares a dynamic vector<node*> and assigns a new vector to it, which will result in a compile-time error as the types are incompatible.

Try this out

```
node *createNode(int indexVal)
{
    node* n = new node();
    n->index = indexVal;
    n->sol = new vector<int>;
    n->children = new vector<node *>;
    return n;
}

void addChildren(node* curr, node* child)
{
    curr->children->push_back(child);
}
```